# Не выводиться текущее значения поля input в consol

Tags: javascript

Проблема заключается в том что не выводиться текущие значение inputa в `console.log`. При этом `class FormElement` никак видоизменять нельзя.

**Вывод в консоль:**

```js
function getInfo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Value-Name: ', elName.getValue());
    console.log('Value-Mail: ', elMail.getValue());
    console.log('Value-Password: ', elPassword.getValue());
    console.log('Value-PasswordRepeat: ', elPasswordRepeat.getValue());
    console.log('Value-Checkbox: ', elCheckbox.getValue());
    console.log('Value-Button: ', elButton.getValue());
}
```

```js
class FormElement {
    constructor(name, type, value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }
    showName() {
        console.log(`Name: ${this.name}`);
    }
    getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
class TextElement extends FormElement {
    constructor(name, type, value, params) {
        super(name, type, value);
        const { classInput, parentWrapper, parent } = params;
        this.classInput = classInput;
        this.parentWrapper = parentWrapper;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    createField(placeholder) {
        const newElement = document.createElement('label');
        newElement.classList.add(`form__label`);
        newElement.innerHTML = `<input class='form__input ${this.classInput}' placeholder="${placeholder}" name="${this.name}"type="${this.type}" value="${this.value}" required>`
        this.parentWrapper.append(newElement);
        return this.parent.append(this.parentWrapper);
    }
}
const elName = new TextElement('name', 'text', '',{
    classInput: 'js--input-name',
    parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
    parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elName.createField('Введите пожалуйста свое имя');

const elMail = new TextElement('email', 'email', '', {
    classInput: 'js--input-email',
    parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
    parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elMail.createField('Введите пожалуйста ваш электронный адрес');

const elPassword = new TextElement('password', 'password', '', {
    classInput: 'js--input-password',
    parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
    parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elPassword.createField('Введите пожалуйста пароль');


const elPasswordRepeat = new TextElement('password-repeat', 'password', '', {
    classInput: 'js--input-password',
    parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
    parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elPasswordRepeat.createField('Введите пожалуйста повторно пароль');



class CheckboxElement extends FormElement {
    constructor(name, type, value, params) {
        super(name, type, value);
        const { classLabel, classInput, parentWrapper, parent } = params;
        this.classLabel = classLabel;
        this.classInput = classInput;
        this.parentWrapper = parentWrapper;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    createField(check) {
        const newElement = document.createElement('label');
        newElement.classList.add(`form__label`);
        newElement.classList.add(`${this.classLabel}`);
        newElement.innerHTML = `<input class='form__input form__input-checkbox ${this.classInput}' name="${this.name}" type="${this.type}" value="${this.value}" ${check} required>`+
                            `<p class="form__text">I agree all statements in <a class="form__link" href="#">Terms of service</a></p>`;
        this.parentWrapper.append(newElement);
        return this.parent.append(this.parentWrapper);

    }

}
const elCheckbox = new CheckboxElement('checkbox', 'checkbox', 'agreement', {
    classLabel: 'form__label-checkbox',
    classInput: 'js--input-password',
    parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
    parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
})
elCheckbox.createField(false);




class ButtonElement extends FormElement {
    constructor(name, type, value, params) {
        super(name, type, value);
        const { parentWrapper, parent } = params;
        this.parentWrapper = parentWrapper;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    createField() {
        const newElement = document.createElement('button');
        newElement.classList.add('form__button');
        newElement.classList.add('js--form__button');
        newElement.setAttribute('name',this.name);
        newElement.setAttribute('type', this.type);
        newElement.setAttribute('value', this.value);
        newElement.textContent = 'Register';
        this.parentWrapper.append(newElement);
        this.parent.append(this.parentWrapper);
        return newElement.addEventListener('click', getInfo)
    }
}
const elButton = new ButtonElement('button', 'submit', 'submit',{
    parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
    parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elButton.createField();
function getInfo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Value-Name: ', elName.getValue());
    console.log('Value-Mail: ', elMail.getValue());
    console.log('Value-Password: ', elPassword.getValue());
    console.log('Value-PasswordRepeat: ', elPasswordRepeat.getValue());
    console.log('Value-Checkbox: ', elCheckbox.getValue());
    console.log('Value-Button: ', elButton.getValue());
}
```

```html
<form class="form js--form" >
        <div class="form__container js--form_container"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Вы в классе **TextElement** создаете **input**, однако нет обработчиков события изменения элемента. Вам необходимо для ваших создаваемых input добавить событие **oninput**, которое будет обновлять поле name. [Вот тут в ответе показывал вам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1517507/1517510#1517510) как это можно сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что не выводиться текущие значение inputa в console.log

Они выводятся... Только все значения равны "пусто", т.к. их никто не меняет в ходе работы.

Предложу такой вариант "корректировки" значений.

```js
class FormElement {
  constructor(name, type, value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
  }
  showName() {
    console.log(`Name: ${this.name}`);
  }
  getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
class TextElement extends FormElement {
  constructor(name, type, value, params) {
    super(name, type, value);
    const {
      classInput,
      parentWrapper,
      parent
    } = params;
    this.classInput = classInput;
    this.parentWrapper = parentWrapper;
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  createField(placeholder) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('label');
    newElement.classList.add(`form__label`);
    newElement.innerHTML = `<input class='form__input ${this.classInput}' placeholder="${placeholder}" name="${this.name}"type="${this.type}" value="${this.value}" required>`
    const self = this
    newElement.addEventListener('input', e => {
      self.value = e.target.value
    })
    this.parentWrapper.append(newElement);
    return this.parent.append(this.parentWrapper);
  }
}
const elName = new TextElement('name', 'text', '', {
  classInput: 'js--input-name',
  parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
  parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elName.createField('Введите пожалуйста свое имя');

const elMail = new TextElement('email', 'email', '', {
  classInput: 'js--input-email',
  parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
  parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elMail.createField('Введите пожалуйста ваш электронный адрес');

const elPassword = new TextElement('password', 'password', '', {
  classInput: 'js--input-password',
  parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
  parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elPassword.createField('Введите пожалуйста пароль');


const elPasswordRepeat = new TextElement('password-repeat', 'password', '', {
  classInput: 'js--input-password',
  parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
  parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elPasswordRepeat.createField('Введите пожалуйста повторно пароль');



class CheckboxElement extends FormElement {
  constructor(name, type, value, params) {
    super(name, type, value);
    const {
      classLabel,
      classInput,
      parentWrapper,
      parent
    } = params;
    this.classLabel = classLabel;
    this.classInput = classInput;
    this.parentWrapper = parentWrapper;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.value = false
  }
  createField(check) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('label');
    newElement.classList.add(`form__label`);
    newElement.classList.add(`${this.classLabel}`);
    newElement.innerHTML = `<input class='form__input form__input-checkbox ${this.classInput}' name="${this.name}" type="${this.type}" value="${this.value}" ${check} required>` +
      `<p class="form__text">I agree all statements in <a class="form__link" href="#">Terms of service</a></p>`;
    const self = this
    newElement.addEventListener('change', e => {
      self.value = e.target.checked
    })
    this.parentWrapper.append(newElement);
    return this.parent.append(this.parentWrapper);

  }

}
const elCheckbox = new CheckboxElement('checkbox', 'checkbox', 'agreement', {
  classLabel: 'form__label-checkbox',
  classInput: 'js--input-password',
  parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
  parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
})
elCheckbox.createField(false);




class ButtonElement extends FormElement {
  constructor(name, type, value, params) {
    super(name, type, value);
    const {
      parentWrapper,
      parent
    } = params;
    this.parentWrapper = parentWrapper;
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  createField() {
    const newElement = document.createElement('button');
    newElement.classList.add('form__button');
    newElement.classList.add('js--form__button');
    newElement.setAttribute('name', this.name);
    newElement.setAttribute('type', this.type);
    newElement.setAttribute('value', this.value);
    newElement.textContent = 'Register';
    this.parentWrapper.append(newElement);
    this.parent.append(this.parentWrapper);
    return newElement.addEventListener('click', getInfo)
  }
}
const elButton = new ButtonElement('button', 'submit', 'submit', {
  parentWrapper: document.querySelector('.js--form_container'),
  parent: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
});
elButton.createField();

function getInfo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Value-Name: ', elName.getValue());
  console.log('Value-Mail: ', elMail.getValue());
  console.log('Value-Password: ', elPassword.getValue());
  console.log('Value-PasswordRepeat: ', elPasswordRepeat.getValue());
  console.log('Value-Checkbox: ', elCheckbox.getValue());
  console.log('Value-Button: ', elButton.getValue());
}
```

```html
<form class="form js--form">
  <div class="form__container js--form_container"></div>
</form>
```